# Apply an image on a plane using Geometry Node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I created a material named `pepper` with Shader Editor :

[image: Material pepper]

It works fine when I manually apply the material to a mesh plane using the Material Property menu.

But then I tried to get the same result by applying this Geometry Node modifier (`node_1`) to a new object :

[image: Geometry Node Node_1]
[image: modifier Geometry Node]

The result is on the left side : a red plane with no image.

**Any idea on what I did wrong ?**

(I am using blender 3.4)

[image: result]

Comment: What went wrong is you didn't UV unwrap your procedural plane. This is why it has a color existing on the image texture, but it's a solid color (it's a color in the bottom-left of the texture, at <0, 0> coordinate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Markus von Broady pointed out to me (thanks to him), my problem is that I have not unwrapped my procedural plane. After a short search on the internet I found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/02XNGOVpSV4?start=280) that explains step by step how to unwrap an object from Goemetry Node in blender 3.3 alpha.

First, we need to add an Attribute Node to the `pepper` material definition  with the name `UVvector` for example:

[image: New pepper material]

Then in Geometry Node, add a UV Unwrap node and link it to Material Output.

[image: New Geometry Node]

Finally, the name of the `UVvector` attribute must be added to the definition of the output modifier

[image: New modifier parameters]

And it all works!

[image: it all works]

Comment: Keep in mind that there's a "grid" node that comes with `uv_map` attribute already containing the default uv map for a plane.